# If someone instigates the end of a relationship, what is the term for the other party?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

When discussing a person that has chosen to end a relationship, particularly a romantic or intimate one, I have chosen to use the word **instigator**. What is the complementary word that describes the person that is being broken up with?

I'm open to using a variation of instigator. In essence, I'm looking for a pair of words that are neater than the *breakerupper* and the *breakupee*.

**EDIT**

Thanks for all suggestions and comments so far. Here is some additional context in reponse:

The terms should be neutral in their emotional content, as far as is possible. They need to cover a range of situations for every combination of breakerupper or breakupee having been right/wrong/aggressive/justified etc. For example, someone may instigate a break up because their partner is abusive so a term like *jilted* would be inappropriate. Similarly, terms which make assumptions about the reason for a break up should be avoided (e.g., cheater). Further, the words should be as formal as possible so although dumper and dumpee are common and valid, I'm hunting for something a little more high-brow sounding!

**EDIT 2**

As suggested in the comments, I'm open to very short phrases which are a more than a single word but are still concise.

Comment: depending on the breakup: the "cheater" and the "broken hearted".

Comment: I get that you're looking for a neater term which is why I'll just comment without answering, but dumper and dumpee are the most common I've heard, I don't recall ever hearing another term used

Comment: "*breakerupper*" I love this term!

Comment: @DKNguyen - you may enjoy a particular NZ film - "The Breaker Upperers" :D

Comment: "Instigate" isn't really the right word here;  it means "to goad or persuade someone else into doing something".  Maybe you mean "initiate"/"initiator" instead?

Comment: The context and restrictions should have been mentioned earlier, c'est la vie, better late than never.

Comment: Perhaps looking for a single word is making it harder to find the answer. Consider using a combination of two or more words. Since you're looking for something formal, that will open possibilities like "the departing partner" and "the remaining partner" or even "the one who leaves" and "the one who is being left".

Comment: >> something a little more high-brow **sounding** There exists '[estrange](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/estrange)' which in some dictionaries has an associated noun '[estranger](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/estrange#other-words)' - one who [estranges](https://wikidiff.com/estrange/estranger).  I couldn't find it, but you could possibly coin 'estrangee'.  I expect it would be intuited correctly by the majority of (*high-brow*) readers.

Comment: Except "estrange" doesn't mean to break up with, as your link proves.

Comment: FWIW I don't think your choice of "instigator" meets your own requirements for the other side. It's not a neutral word but one loaded with the implication that there's something bad or troublesome about the break-up.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert - So far your suggestion for initiator is my favourite. Could you put that as an answer if you come up with it's complementary word/phrase so I can accept it?

Comment: The "recipient" helps to imply the one-way aspect of the beginning of the break-up.

Comment: @chiliNUT I wonder if dumper/dumpee is a more American usage? It's not something I have heard this side of the Atlantic. Perhaps others would like to comment?

Comment: From the many answers all of which propose something that is not normally used, we can gather that 'there isn't really a good label for either party that is accepted in general. 'Dumper/dumpee' is probably the one that sounds the least 'not right', but they still sound like a neologism every time. You just don't label people for this situation with nouns this way. 'X dumped Y' is as far as it goes.

Comment: @Anton: I can't speak for outside the U.S., but the *only* mostly neutral terminology I've ever heard used in the U.S. (lived in Mid-Atlantic region most of my life, plus some time in Seattle and New York) is dumper/dumpee. There just isn't a good formal word for the roles that anyone would actually use.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good counterpart to "initiator" that means "the person who didn't initiate the breakup".  I'll post something if I come up with anything, though.

Answer (score 13):

I'd probably describe such a person as the ***[dumpee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumpee#English)***, based on the common *informal* use of "to dump" to mean "to break up a relationship with" cf the definition below from [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dump#Verb):

> 6. (transitive, informal) To end a romantic relationship with.
>
> - Sarah dumped Nelson after finding out he was cheating on her.

Comment: I think "the dumped" is much better than "the dumpee".

Comment: @PeterShor I do not. Adjectives (including participles) cannot generally be used substantively in English (typically requiring a dummy pronoun e.g. "the dumped one"), whereas -ee (and -er) are pretty productive at forming object (and agent) nouns

Comment: "Dumper" and "Dumpee" was my first instinct too, though it probably shouldn't be used in formal settings.

Comment: A similar, but perhaps less pejorative set would be splitter/splittee.  @Tristan you're correct, but there is a tendency these days to overuse the er/or->ee construct.  Eg: the object of a mentor is a protégé, not a mentee.  </soapbox>

Comment: I don't think I'd consider dumping perjorative, although I can certainly see why others might. Unfortunately splittee doesn't work for me because the verb is "split up" not "split", and whilst a double construction is common with -er (e.g. "splitter upper") I've not seen similar with -ee (or an alternative construction for using it with phrasal verbs e.g. "up-splittee"). I do agree that use of -er/or > -ee (where a good word already exists) does come across buzzwordy though

Comment: @mcalex: Without context, I would never think of relationships when I heard "splitter" (and I'd never think of "splittee" as a word at all). Dumping someone has been given slight negative connotations (for dumb reasons; it's *good* to end a relationship that isn't working out rather than dragging it out), but it's accurate. And the concept of "splitting" has even worse negative connotations (because it usually refers to a parent "splitting on the family", which means abandoning those you support with little or no notice, not merely ending a relationship where there is no dependency yet).

Answer (score 10):

This is a question with many appropriate answers. Here are two more suggestions:

Use the nouns **forsaken** or **forlorn**

First, *forsaken*:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forsake)  *forsake*, verb
> to leave someone for ever, especially when they need you

Hence, *forsaken* as a participle noun:

"*She, the forsaken, was in tears after he left*"

Second, regarding *forlorn*, we have:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/forlorn)
> *forlorn*, adjective
> alone and unhappy; left alone and not cared for

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forlorn)
> *forlorn*, adjective
> sad and lonely because of isolation or desertion

We may use the word as an adjectival noun:

"*He, the forlorn, was deep in sorrow*"

Of these two I prefer *forsaken*, because it places slightly more emphasis on the state of the person as a result of another's leaving. *forlorn* is more simply focused on the state of the person.

For an emotional use of *forsake*, see the lyrics from the film “High Noon”

> [Smule](https://www.smule.com/song/frankie-laine-high-noon-do-not-forsake-me-karaoke-lyrics/152506657_945446/arrangement)
> *Do not forsake me, oh my darlin',
>
> on this our wedding day.
>
> Do not forsake me, oh my darlin',
>
> wait, wait along
>
> …*

{I only quote the opening verse; there is more)

Comment: Lol, I'm using forsaken instead of dumpee from this point on. 10/10

Answer (score 7):

Although these terms are not strictly referring to romantic breakups, surrounded by the right context, they will carry the meaning you are looking for:

The ***abandoner***

> a person or thing that abandons ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/abandoner))

and the ***abandoned***

> having been deserted or left ([OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=abandoned%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsalFqGxxe30XMw1wu-hg4wMqS40Dg%3A1661164006787&ei=5lkDY8y_L8upgQbgq4mIAg&ved=0ahUKEwjMyqaUntr5AhXLVMAKHeBVAiEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=abandoned%20meaning&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCQgAEEMQRhD_ATIHCAAQsQMQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIECAAQQzIGCAAQHhAHMgYIABAeEAcyBggAEB4QBzIGCAAQHhAHOgcIABBHELADSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUMcFWMcFYJwOaAFwAXgAgAFUiAFUkgEBMZgBAKABAcgBCMABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz))

In *[Life After Divorce](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Life_After_Divorce/Y5KjAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)* (2012), Sharon Wegscheider-Cruse writes:

> The real difference between ***“the abandoner”*** and ***“the abandoned”*** is that emotionally the sense of their spouse's leaving them came at different times.

Here is another instance:

> Some marriages even appear to be sustained by a process whereby the partners alternate between the roles of ***the abandoner*** and ***the abandoned***. 
>  (*[Stress And The Family: Coping With Catastrophe](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eTiPDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT94&dq=%22the%20abandoner%20and%20the%20abandoned%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjz3omRn9r5AhWjTEEAHUvUAJ8Q6AF6BAgJEAI)*, Charles R. Figley, ‎Hamilton I. McCubbin, 2016)

I can understand the use of *instigator* as in ***the instigator of the breakup***. Its pair term could be ***the victim***, but breakups with only one victim are rather rare...

Comment: Thanks for the thhoughtful contribution but, again, abandon is quite a loaded word. Seems like I'm searching for a word that doesn't appear in English as of yet!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by loaded, but anyway. Don't get stuck on the idea that you can only express a meaning in one particular way. Language is a tool in your hands and you can turn it and bend it in such a way as to convey what you want.

Comment: Emotionally-charged is perhaps more accurate than loaded. Abandon, in the context of interpersonal relationships, to me evokes quite a dramatic image. A mother abandoning her child is different to a manager abandoning a project.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. But do note that the subject of breakups _**is**_ emotionally charged. On the other hand it is good to be picky with words. I am, too. I find we nowadays settle too easily for just any popular word, rather than carefully thinking of the term we need. I must be getting old I guess :)

Answer (score 6):

The solution could lie with Gwyneth Paltrow's infamous "conscious uncoupling”

> When Chris Martin and Gwyneth Paltrow split back in 2014, they released a statement noting instead of just breaking up they were **“conscious uncoupling.”** It’s been a phrase that has followed Gwyneth Paltrow in particular ever since and she’s finally chosen to explain where the terminology came from. Apparently, it was a term a therapist had used to get them on the same page about exiting their marriage but still co-parenting their kids.

The **uncoupler** would be the partner who ends the relationship while the partner  who is left alone (to mend their heart) could be termed the **uncoupled**

There is also a new TV show called, **[Uncoupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncoupled)**

> The series stars Neil Patrick Harris as a newly single gay Manhattanite navigating the dating scene for the first time in 17 years **after getting abruptly dumped** by his long-term partner

Comment: Appreciate the neutrality of this one. I wonder if the variation decouple might also work. Although this makes me think of train carriages, rather than breakups.

Answer (score 6):

How about the **jilter** and the **jilted**.

> **jilt** TRANSITIVE VERB
> to reject or cast aside (a lover or sweetheart), esp. abruptly or unfeelingly
> [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/jilt)

Comment: That works for dates and ["jilted at the altar"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jilted+at+the+altar%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsamT_fQIrZKI6PV71WIqDYyNhZbtg%3A1661170504507&ei=SHMDY6O7HqeF9u8PpZS1iA8&ved=0ahUKEwij_9Outtr5AhWngv0HHSVKDfEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22jilted+at+the+altar%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBggAEB4QFjIICAAQHhAPEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWOgQIIxAnOgYIABAeEAdKBAhBGABKBAhGGABQAFjbE2DtGWgAcAB4AIABdIgBuwKSAQMxLjKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz) scenarios, but less well for long-term relationships or marriages.

Comment: Sounds a bit old-fashioned for my ears, but I can't think of a recent term that works better.

Comment: Or even *the jiltee*

Answer (score 5):

As you want a more formal word than *dumpee*, there is ***leavee***. It is used in the context of divorce also.

> The person in a relationship who is left by the other. - [*Wiktionary*](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/leavee)

It even appears in a movie line by Woody Allen, in *Everyone Says I Love You*:

> In a relationship, it is better to be the leaver than the leavee. - [*imdb.com*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116242/characters/nm0000095)

Answer (score 0):

**Respondent**

1. a defendant in a lawsuit, especially one in an appeals or divorce case.

The use in a divorce case is the relevant one.

It's 'instigator' pair-word is *Petitioner*.